# Problem while accessing Java method through XSLT-1.0

Tags: xslt, xalan

Problems while accessing Java method through XSL .'I have a java class DirectoryReader.java with a static method totalPhotos which returns a int. In my XSL I have defined a namespace: `xmlns:dirReader="xalan://com.mngi.eidos.util.DirectoryReader` and I am trying to access the totalPhotos method like:

```
<xsl:variable name="totalPhotos" select="dirReader:totalPhotos($PhotoPath)"/>
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong in my approach ?

I still get the following error

> `ERROR: 'The first argument to the
>   non-static Java function 'totalPhotos'
>   is not a valid object reference`

Answer (score 2):

Either the method `totalPhotos` must be static, or you must first create an instance of the class and pass that as the first argument to the call.

```
<xsl:variable name="dr" select="dirReader:new(....)"/>
<xsl:variable name="totalPhotos" select="dirReader:totalPhotos($dr,$PhotoPath)"/>
```

Adjust dirReader constructor arguments to your situation